# Slide out navigation programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking for a slide out navigation. I am not using cocoa pods and storyboard. Any good reference available so that my side view slides on top of the centre view. I followed rayweinderlich sample code however the side menu comes under the main view.Here is the shadow code and animation code

```
if shouldShowShadow {
    centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
} else {
    centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
}
```

This is the animation method.The centre panel should be at the bottom and side menu should come over

```
     func animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           delay: 0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 0,
                           options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                            self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
            }, completion: completion)
        }

func animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: Bool) {
        if shouldExpand {
            currentState = .leftPanelExpanded
            animateCenterPanelXPosition(
                targetPosition: centerNavigationController.view.frame.width - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
        } else {
            animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { _ in
                self.currentState = .bothCollapsed
                self.leftViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
                self.leftViewController = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how a side panel is added.MenuViewController is the side panel

```
func addChildSidePanelController(_ sidePanelController: MenuViewController) {

    sidePanelController.delegate = centerViewController
    view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, at: 0)

    addChild(sidePanelController)
    sidePanelController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried till now for us to look into. Also provide the links you've seeked guidance from.

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/1005187-how-to-create-your-own-slide-out-panel-navigation,the side menu comes under the centre view.I was hoping for side menu to cover the centre view

Comment: Your question is very broad, as there are numerous solutions to achieve this. For example https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/making-a-hamburger-slide-out-menu-in-swift-3-ef5249b6693e. If you google something like `swift hamburger menu tutorial` you should get some options.

Comment: The under/above effect is simply caused by the shadow position/angle.

Comment: @JeroenJK I tried but I am not using storyboard hence that did not work for my case

Comment: @Cœuri have updated my question.Thanks